# If first checkbox ticked then disable rest cf7

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have more than one checkbox section using CF7 for wordpress.

If the user selects Anytime / Any Day then I would like to disable or hide the other checkboxes.

Here is my code for the checkboxes

```
<div class="column one">
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Best Day for Visit</strong>
[checkbox* best-day "Any Day" "Mon" "Tues" "Weds" "Thurs" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"]</p>
</div>

<div class="column one">
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Best Time of Day For Visit</strong>
[checkbox* contact-time label_first "Anytime" "AM" "PM"]
</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us and JS attempts you've made at getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Conditional Fields Plugin for this.

Works perfect for your Job. Here is an General Tutorial, if you need a complete code i can edit tomorrow (just on mobile right now)

https://conditional-fields-cf7.bdwm.be/conditional-fields-for-contact-form-7-tutorial/